# How to run multiple instances of Laravel on the same domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I have Apache 2.4 running on Windows Server 2012 with PHP 5.6.23 on port 8080.

Assume that the domain to my server is "serv1.example.com" I need to run 3 Laravel instances `production`,`staging` and `dev` using the following links

```
serv1.example.com:8080/production
serv1.example.com:8080/staging
serv1.example.com:8080/dev
```

I found another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798858/install-multiple-laravel-4-projects-to-sub-directories) which seems to be doing the same thing. But when I tried to do the same thing I get the following error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /dev on this server.
```

Here is what I have done so far. In my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I added the following VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ErrorLog "logs/dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev-access.log" common
    DocumentRoot "C:\www\dev\public"
    ServerName serv1.example.com
    ServerAlias /dev

    <Directory "C:\www\dev">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I changed `c:\www\dev\public\.htaccess` the code to the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/index.php/?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What did I do wrong here? how can I access each instance using the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

Try This one, in your Apache configure file `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerName  serv1.example.com
     ServerAlias serv1.example.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/www/dev/public"

     # Rewrites for pretty URLs, better not to rely on .htaccess.
     <Directory "C:/www/dev/public">
         Options All
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
     </Directory>

# Log file locations
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog "logs/dev-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dev-access.log" common
```

And in your `c:\www\dev\public\.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I hope this would work. for more information follow these links.[Multiple laravelsites on single apache server](https://tutorialedge.net/running-multiple-laravel-5-sites-on-server) , [multiple web sites in single laravel installation](http://laravel.io/forum/12-30-2014-multiple-websites-with-one-laravel-installation)

Comment: This did not work for me. + why would you leave /var/www in there that is lunix thing not windows.

Comment: example was taken from linux installation and I also working with laravel in linux environment. so please change those things.

Comment: it still isn't working. I got the 403 Forbidden error

Comment: check this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447454/apache-giving-403-forbidden-errors

Comment: I am getting closer! thank you for that. so the following link seems to be working fine `http://server1.example.com:8080/mod/terminated` but it should be this `http://server1.example.com:8080/dev/mod/terminated`

Comment: good, you can edit the answer with the values you used to get the answer.

Comment: I edited your answer to my current code which is based on your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115461/discussion-between-sachith-and-jaylen).